# Random IQ Matrix question

Tags: progressive-matrix

[image]

Found this picture in a random Whatsapp group. Someone said it's from one of the free online Mensa tests. Exact source unknown.

Comment: With the tiny amount of information in this grid, and no completely obvious pattern, it feels to me like a minimal description of the finished grid would just be its literal enumeration rather than a description by pattern, regardless of the final tile.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take:

> **c**. The image is a 3d cylinder which is rotated about the x-axis (left-right). I get this from the point in the middle of the white circle which seems to indicate the tip of the tapered point. The pattern is "do nothing, front up $90^\circ$, rotate $180^\circ$, tip down $90^\circ$" and repeat, and read from left to right, top to bottom. This makes the next object **c**.

Comment: It's clearly C. My attempt to express it, in case OP is hesitating. If you run from left to right and from top to bottom the whole matrix, the pattern is rotate the object towards z (the imaginary horizon on your screen) 0°,90°,180°,-90°,0°,90°,180°...

Comment: @user65573; or $0^\circ,90^\circ,180^\circ,270^\circ,360^\circ,450^\circ,\dots$.

Comment: Right! good one! Just in front of my eyes! Then this is the definitive synthesized pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Option b.)

On the grounds of:

> Exactly 1 change of symbol in each row moving from left to right

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

> **C**

Here is the method

> The two symbols on the left and center in any row, add to create the right symbol. Once you add the symbols in the third row, you would have to perform arithmetic with the symbols that are shown in 1st and 2nd columns in 1st row and 2nd and 3rd columns in the 2nd row. If the symbols with the opposite orientation add, they cancel out. But if the symbol is being subtracted, that symbol's orientation must be reversed and henceforth added. If the symbols with the same orientation add, they simply produce the same symbol. This logic would give us option **C**.